# devexpress textedit/mru autocomplete?

Tags: c#, devexpress

is it possible to set `devexpress` `textedit` to get data from the database and make it autocomplete? or is there any tool in `devexpress` to do it?

here is my code

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SystemDatabase"].ConnectionString;                     
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(conn);                                               
SqlCommand mycommand = new SqlCommand("spProduct_Search", sqlconn);                  
mycommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;                                     
sqlconn.Open();                                                                             
 SqlDataReader sdr = mycommand.ExecuteReader();                                             
AutoCompleteStringCollection autotext = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();                        
while (sdr.Read())                                                                                     
{
    autotext.Add(sdr.GetString(0));
}                            
txtProductSearch.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;**Textbox**
txtProductSearch.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;**Textbox**
txtProductSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autotext;**Textbox**
```

if possible i want to change `textbox` to `textedit` a tool from `devexpress` but i dont know how to make a `textedit` autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you want is the LookUpEdit control and it's [AutoSuggest mode](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraEditors.LookUpEdit#autosuggest-mode). Per the documentation, the AutoSuggest mode:

> When a user types in text, the editor fires the AutoSuggest event (LookUpEdit.AutoSuggest \ GridLookUpEdit.AutoSuggest) that runs a custom asynchronous task (a System.Threading.Tasks.Task object). This task performs a search against the given data set, and returns the ICollection object with records that match the entered text. This collection is automatically assigned to the editor's DataSource and its entries appear in the editor drop-down menu.

During this asynchronous event you could execute your database query and populate the ICollection with your result set.

Comment: How would i populate the ```lookupedit``` with the data from my database?

Comment: it works.. all i need is ```lookupedit1.properties.datasource = autotext``` based on my code

Comment: That will work if you have a set data source for your LookUpEdit. If you want it to be able to change based on what a user might be typing into the control, you will want to use the AutoSuggestMode.

Comment: how to make it auto suggest?

Comment: You need to set the LookupEdit's Properties.SearchMode propertyt to AutoSuggest and handle the LookupEdit's AutoSuggest event. There is an example in the documentation link I provided above.